# Send Push Notifications from PHP Server to Android Devices

Tags: php, android, console, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to `send push notifications` to app users and to do that I have written `server side` script in `PHP`.

In many blogs like [this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/) one, I have read that to send notifications from server to Android devices, we need to get `Server Key`, but in one of the recent [tutorial](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204972667-Android-Enabling-Google-Cloud-Messaging-in-Your-Android-Apps) I read about `Browser Key`

So which `key` I need to get, to get my work done, either `Server Key` or `Browser Key`, and may I know the exact `difference` between these `two keys`.

Comment: - Server keys : 
Create and use a server key if your application runs on a server. Do not use this key outside of your server code. For example, do not embed it in a web page. To prevent quota theft, restrict your key so that requests are only allowed from your servers' source IP addresses.

- Browser keys :

Create and use a browser key if your application runs on a client, such as a web browser. To prevent your key from being used on unauthorized sites, only allow referrals from domains you administer.

Comment: @PhuocHuynh so which key I need to use to send push notifications from server side to android devices ? OR .. I can use any key..

Comment: Android -> GCM ->(get registration ids)-> input this id to server -> sever get this id -> push notification to device
Thanks @Sanjeev kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use server key for push notification.

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715572/google-api-keys-what-is-server-key-and-browser-key) for difference between server key and browser key